# How to Display different value of <input type="submit" on hover with CSS within a React Component

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I have a form with `<input type="submit"` for which the `value` is set dynamically (as `currIntValue`).

The goal is to have the `value` displayed as 'Search' when the input is hovered, instead of the `currIntValue`.

I thought to make two inputs and hide/ unhide each on hover but this isn't having the expected result. Basically the `className="int-val"` hides when hovered and quickly reappears/ disappears repetitively.

Here is a basic implementation of what I am trying to describe above:

```css
.int-val {
  display: inline;
 }

.int-val:hover {
  display: none;
}

.search-val {
  display: none;
}

.search-val:hover {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value={currIntValue} className="int-val"/>
<input type="submit" value='Search' className="search-val"/>
```

If this is possible just using CSS, where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `className` is javascript/react. Are you writing React or HTML?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860058/change-text-on-mouse-over-and-change-back-on-mouse-out

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. It is React.

Comment: @GLalor Yes, I did see that solution but wrapping each in spans did not seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap both `input` into a `label` and then use `:hover` in `label`.

Your css is not working because

..when you hover on `.int-val`, it hide itself *(becomes out of flow)*

..then immediately your cursor comes at `.search-val` which hide `.search-val`

..then again your cursor comes at `.int-val` which hide itself again

..and this process became like never ending process.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.int-val {
  display: inline;
}

label:hover .search-val {
  display: inline;
}

label:hover .int-val {
  display: none;
}

.search-val {
  display: none;
}

input {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="submit" value={currIntValue} class="int-val"/>
  <input type="submit" value='Search' class="search-val"/>
</label>
```

Comment: ```label``` worked. Could you possibly help me understand why?